# Rakudo test suite progression?

Tags: raku, rakudo

There used to be a graph that tracked the implementation of Perl6 against the test suite for Perl6. I was interested in watching it progress (and, regress). What happened to that graph, it used to be hosted on the site www.rakudo.de

Is there any other easy way an outsider can get an idea of where Rakudo stands in relation to the perfected spec? What features is it yet-missing?

Answer (score 6):

As for he second question, the way is the [feature comparison matrix](http://perl6.org/compilers/features).

There is no official place for spectest graphs, but [there are some good ones too](https://github.com/flussence/specgraphs/blob/master/impls.png)

Answer (score 5):

I used to run a cron job that generated the graph, and eventually stopped it. The reason was that lots of people put way too much weight into the numbers of that graph, and generally assumed that the test suit was perfect, covering all features of the spec homogeneously etc.

In addition there's no easy way to count the number of total tests, making the numbers not very reliable.

In the end I had the feeling that the graph was more misleading than informative.

The best way to get a feeling for the progress is to become an insider, ie start playing with Rakudo. It's still lots slower than Perl 5 (though not as much as it used to be), but it's quite usable, and fun to use.

Comment: I did like it, too. It conveyed a feeling of progress. People like coloured graphes.. informative or not ;) Still I understand why you removed it, though.